# Multiple WHERE [date] 'is NULL' OR <= [date] clauses - also replace NULL value with text

Tags: sql

I'm a complete newbie to SQL so I apologise if I'm overthinking things and the solution is actually a lot easier than I first thought.

I have a query where I want a list of results where the date of an appointment is within the last x months or is NULL, the person joined the company more than a month ago and is aged between 18 and 21. When the result is NULL then I want text to say 'Missing'.

The code below gives me the expected number of rows and I am currently importing it into Excel, manually adding a column for each appointment type referencing the date or writing 'Missing' if the date isn't there. I want to avoid having to do this.

I've tried using COALESCE but I got fewer results than I should have. Couldn't get my head around how to set out isnull().

```
SELECT   Child.fullname AS Person, 
     Child.parentcustomeridname AS Family, 
     Child.btb_childinformationdateenteredbtb AS [Date Joined], 
     Child.owneridname AS Manager, 
     Child.btb_personalinformationage AS Age, 
     Child.btb_childhealthlastdentaldate AS [Last Dental Date], 
     Child.btb_childhealthlastlacmedical AS [Last Medical], 
     Child.btb_childhealthlastopticiandate AS [Last Optician], 
     Child.btb_childhealthotherhealthcommentary AS [Other Health Commentary] 
FROM dbo.FilteredBusinessUnit Fil
RIGHT JOIN dbo.FilteredAccount Family 
ON Fil.businessunitid=Family.owningbusinessunit
RIGHT JOIN dbo.FilteredContact Child 
ON Child.accountid=Family.accountid
WHERE    (Child.btb_childhealthlastlacmedical is NULL 
OR       Child.btb_childhealthlastlacmedical <= DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE()) 
OR       Child.btb_childhealthlastdentaldate is NULL 
OR       Child.btb_childhealthlastdentaldate <= DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE())
OR       Child.btb_childhealthlastopticiandate is NULL 
OR       Child.btb_childhealthlastopticiandate <= DATEADD(month, -24, GETDATE()) )
AND      Child.customertypecode = 1  
AND      Child.owningbusinessunit = 'London Office'
AND      (Child.btb_personalinformationage >= 18 
AND      Child.btb_personalinformationage <= 21)
AND      Child.statecode = 0 
AND      Child.btb_childinformationdateenteredbtb <= DATEADD(month, -1,  GETDATE()) 
ORDER BY 1
```

The results should be: people who may have attended 1/3 or 2/3 appointments, people who've attended none. Where a date is not present there should be text saying 'Missing'

Comment: RIGHT JOIN... Most people find `main table left join optional data` much easier to understand than `optional data right join main table`.

Comment: Why do you even join FilteredBusinessUnit and businessunitid? You don't select any values from these tables.

Comment: @jarlh Well spotted, I think I must have selected a value from it previously but forgot to remove the join. Should I update the code above?

Comment: You should simplify your problem as much as possible: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Just use a case statement in your select:

```
case when Child.btb_childhealthlastdentaldate is not null 
then child.btb_childhealthlastdentaldate else 'Missing'  AS [Last 
Dental Date],
```

You may need to convert the date to a string in order for this to work in which case:

```
Case when Child.btb_childhealthlastdentaldate is not null 
then cast(child.btb_childhealthlastdentaldate as varchar) 
else 'Missing' end AS [Last Dental Date],
```

to answer your query about the possible erroring with bad data...

```
CASE WHEN TRY_CAST(Child.btb_childhealthlastdentaldate as datetime) is not null 
THEN CAST(child.btb_childhealthlastdentaldate as varchar) 
ELSE 'Missing' END AS [Last Dental Date],
```

For a formatted string:

```
CASE WHEN TRY_CAST(Child.btb_childhealthlastdentaldate as datetime) is not null 
THEN FORMAT(child.btb_childhealthlastdentaldate,'dd/MM/yyyy') 
ELSE 'Missing' END AS [Last Dental Date],
```

OK, so here is another version this time avoiding TRY_CAST

```
CASE WHEN ISDATE(Child.btb_childhealthlastdentaldate) =1 
THEN FORMAT(child.btb_childhealthlastdentaldate,'dd/MM/yyyy') 
ELSE 'Missing' END AS [Last Dental Date],
```

Comment: @iainc Thanks, the second piece of code worked when putting 'end' before the AS. Is there an alternative to using varchar? I've had issues in the past ('The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value' error message) so I've used GETDATE instead.

Comment: story of my life. Always forget the end when i'm in a hurry. Apologies.

Comment: @iainc If varchar is the only option, is there a way display the date as a short date (i.e DD/MM/YY) as it's currently DDD/MM/YYYY HH:MM

Comment: 'TRY_CAST' is not a recognized built-in function name